# Why do polynomial norms only consider the coefficients? Rather than the basis as well?

Tags: normed-spaces

Why do polynomial norms only consider the coefficients? Rather than the basis as well?

It seems a bit illogical to say that $\|p\|_1=\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|$, but e.g. $\|f\|_1=\sum_{j=0}^k \| f^{(j)}\|_{\infty}$ (assuming $f\in C^k$).

Maybe this is just some intuition regarding "what's the important property that we want to measure in the construct". So for polynomials one's often interested in the coefficients (since the basis is known).

Comment: It is what is called an intrinsic concept, like determinant or trace, independant of any basis. Nothing more to say.